# Add previous value to each hash value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash with integer values:

```
h = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 1,
  d: 2,
  e: 2,
}
```

I need to add `100` to the first value, and for the second value and on, I need to add the preceding value to the original value to get:

```
{
  a: 101,
  b: 102,
  c: 103,
  d: 105,
  e: 107,
}
```

Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Is your issue not being able to run the `.each` or you need help with the algorithm itself?

Comment: I was asking if there is a better ruby way to achieve this @elvinas

Comment: Time is not crucial to your issue. You need to simplify the hash to make your point.

Comment: This is called *prefix-sum* or *scan* and is indeed strangely missing from Ruby's collections library.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason for doing so, it's generally not a good idea to assume that hash keys have a particular order.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the hash is generate from a SQL select ordered by date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to calculate the total sum:

```
h = { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 2, e: 2}

h.inject(100) { |s, (k, v)| s + v }
#=> 107
```

And while doing so, you can also set the hash values to get an accumulated sum:

```
h.inject(100) { |s, (k, v)| h[k] = s + v }

h #=> {:a=>101, :b=>102, :c=>103, :d=>105, :e=>107}
```

Comment: This problem has many guises, one being to convert a discrete probability density function to a cumulative distribution function. You've provided a nice way of doing that. Is this a first: your answer having been edited?

Comment: @CarySwoveland ha! I'm usually the one editing answers to include links :-) Seems like I was in a hurry.

Answer (score 3):

Immutable solution that does not modify the input:

```
h.each_with_object({sum: 100, outcome: {}}) do |(k, v), acc|
  acc[:outcome][k] = acc[:sum] += v
end
#⇒ {:sum=>107, :outcome=>{:a=>101, :b=>102, :c=>103, :d=>105, :e=>107}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just keep track of the sum as an external variable:

```
sum = 100
h.transform_values{|v| sum += v} # => {:a=>101, :b=>102, :c=>103, :d=>105, :e=>107}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the most efficient solution, but it is definitely nice and readable.

```
accumulated_sum = 0
h.each do |key, value|
  accumulated_sum += value
  hash[key] = 100 + accumulated_sum
end
```

Comment: I edited your answer according to my edit of the question.